# How do I scrape information from website source code/html using R?

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping

I am pretty new to webscraping and I am trying to build a scraper that accesses information in the website's source code/html using R.

Specifically, I want to be able to determine whether a (number of) website(s) has an id with a certain text: "google_ads_iframe". The id will always be longer than this, so I think I will have to use a wildcard.

I have tried several options (see below), but so far nothing has worked.

1st method:

```
doc <- htmlTreeParse("http://www.funda.nl/") 

data <- xpathSApply(doc, "//div[contains(@id, 'google_ads_iframe')]", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
```

Error message reads:

```
Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "XMLDocumentContent"
```

2nd method:

```
scrapestuff <- scrape(url = "http://www.funda.nl/", parse = T, headers = T)

x <- xpathSApply(scrapestuff[[1]],"//div[contains(@class, 'google_ads_iframe')]",xmlValue)
```

x returns as an empty list.

3rd method:

```
scrapestuff <- read_html("http://www.funda.nl/")
hh <- htmlParse(scrapestuff, asText=T)
x <- xpathSApply(hh,"//div[contains(@id, 'google_ads_iframe')]",xmlValue)
```

Again, x is returned as an empty list.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, so any help would be really great!

Comment: What packages are the functions from?

Comment: The easy way to count the number of occurrences in text is by using `sum(stringr::str_count(scrapestuff, "google_ads_iframe"))` if scrapestuff could be character. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15356666/5967807).

Comment: Actually, for HTML/XML the easy way to count the number of occurrences in HTML/XML is by using—for example—`xml_find_first(pg, "count(.//div[contains(@class, 'featured')])")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My ad blocker is probably preventing me from seeing google ads iframes, but you don't have to waste cycles with additional R functions to test for the presence of something. Let the optimized C functions in `libxml2` (which underpins `rvest` and the `xml2` package) do the work for you and just wrap your XPath with `boolean()`:

```
library(xml2)

pg <- read_html("http://www.funda.nl/")

xml_find_lgl(pg, "boolean(.//div[contains(@class, 'featured')])")
## [1] TRUE

xml_find_lgl(pg, "boolean(.//div[contains(@class, 'futured')])")
## [1] FALSE
```

One other issue you'll need to deal with is that the google ads iframes are most likely being generated after page-load with javascript, which means using RSelenium to grab the page source (you can then use this method with the resultant page source).

**UPDATE**

I found a page example with `google_ads_iframe` in it:

```
pg <- read_html("http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jtizx.html")

xml_find_lgl(pg, "boolean(.//div[iframe[contains(@id, 'google_ads_iframe')]])")
## [1] TRUE

xml_find_first(pg, "count(.//div[iframe[contains(@id, 'google_ads_iframe')]])")
## [1] 3
```

That's a rendered page, though, and I suspect you'll still need to use RSelenium to do the page grabbing. Here's how to do that (if you're on a reasonable operating system and have phantomjs installed, otherwise use it with Firefox):

```
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer()
phantom_js <- phantom(pjs_cmd='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs', extras=c("--ssl-protocol=any"))
capabilities <- list(phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.70 Safari/537.3")
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", extraCapabilities=capabilities)
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate(URL)
raw_html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

pg <- read_html()
...

# eventually (when done)
phantom_js$stop()
```

**NOTE**

The XPath I used with the codepen example (since it has a google ads iframe) was necessary. Here's the snippet where the iframe exists:

```
<div id="div-gpt-ad-1379506098645-3" style="width:720px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:none;">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1379506098645-3'); });
  </script>
  <iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/16833175/SmallPS_0" name="google_ads_iframe_/16833175/SmallPS_0" width="723" height="170" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" src="javascript:&quot;<html><body style='background:transparent'></body></html>&quot;" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;"></iframe></div>
```

The `iframe` tag is a child of the `div` so if you want to target the `div` first you then have to add the child target if you want to find an attribute in it.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't quite work. Your example runs fine. When use this as an example for the following, it doesn't and returns false, even though I know it should be true:                                         xml_find_lgl(pg, "boolean(.//div[contains(@id, google_ads_iframe')])")

Comment: because the div does not contain that id, it contains an iframe with that id which is kinda why i used th example i did.

Comment: In a second step I want to see whether a certain source is used for the ad and I am using an src. I tried the following, but it didn't work: xml_find_lgl(pg, "boolean(.//div[iframe[contains(@src, 'googleadservices.com')]])")

Comment: aren't those generally in the `img`or `script` tags? I know `iframe`s can have `src` attributes as well but for google ads they are usually `javascript` and not using that domain.

Comment: I think the set up differs, but generally you are probably right. I tried script instead of iframe, but that didn't yield any results either. I also tried leaving out div.

Comment: I pasted the html here (for a different website, because it seemed like the former did not have the text i was looking for) http://pastebin.com/Jx2gQpsr

Comment: `xml_find_lgl(pg, "boolean(.//script[contains(@src, 'googleadservices.com')])")` seems to work

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help!